# Adding name="" attribute to form tag with simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I need to make this:

```
<% simple_form_for :list_signup, :url => 'http://foobar.com" do |f| %>
...
```

Output:

```
<form name="myForm" action="http://foobar.com" class="list_signup" method="post">
...
```

I can't figure out how to add the name attribute and can't figure it out from the documentation at http://simple-form.plataformatec.com.br/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<% simple_form_for :list_signup, :url => 'http://foobar.com', :html => {:name => 'foo'} do |f| %>
```

Comment: This works if I make an adjustment for using an older version of ruby:
`<% simple_form_for :list_signup, :url => 'http://foobar.com', :html => {:name => 'myForm'} %>` If you'll edit your answer, I'll check it.